# How to get value on button click in array react native

Tags: react-native

Hello please help me to sort out from this error.

```
btnDynamic()
{
  return myArr.map(function(data,index){
      return(
        <TouchableHighlight key={index}  onPress={()=> this.btnCLick()} style={styles.btn} underlayColor='transparent'>
            <View style={{alignItems:'center',justifyContent:'center'}}>
                <Text ref={index} style={{fontSize:6,fontWeight:'bold'}}>{data.category}</Text>
            </View>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      )
  });

}
```

above is my function which gives multiple buttons depend on my another function gives response.
but main problem is button click method gives an error like this.

"this.btnCLick is not a function.(in _this3.btnCLick()),this3.btnClick" is undefine.

this is my btn Click function

```
btnCLick(text){
  Alert.alert("Button Is Clicked",text);
}
```

please guys help me to solve this error.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You lose *this* context when not using fat arrow syntax with `.map()`. So fix to: `return myArr.map((data,index) => { ... })` and your fine with that particular error.

Comment: Thank you so much, you are a savior thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

**I would like to share how to get value on button click array react native**

```
const OpenGallery = () => {
      return this.state.photos.map((p, i) => {
        let selectImage = p.node.image.uri;
        return (
          <TouchableOpacity
            key={i}
            onPress={this.selectImage.bind(this, selectImage)}
          >
            <Thumbnail
              square
              style={{
                width: 120,
                height: 120,
                margin: 3
              }}
              source={{ uri: p.node.image.uri }}
            />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        );
      });
    };
```

**Create funtion**

```
selectImage = image => {
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    this.setState({
      isGallery: !this.state.isGallery
    });
    this.selectedImage = image;
  };
```

According to this concept I can access current array value through button click event.

*I hope it will help you.*